# Is it possible to use Skydrive with SVN?

Tags: svn, onedrive

Is it possible to position a SVN repository on Skydrive?

Comment: In case others are wondering what Skydrive actually is (I had to google it): "Cloud storage" by Microsoft: http://skydrive.live.com/

Comment: Do you mean a repository or a working copy? If it's a working copy, I don't see why not, but if it's repository then it would depend how exactly the drive maps itself. But I would suspect you can. Have you tried it? What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if you have some kind of bridging application that maps your account as a drive. Then it's just like any drive on your computer.

I looked into this a while ago but found no decent free application that does this.

[GLADINET](http://www.gladinet.com/index.htm) claims to do this but is not free. (It supports several "cloud storage" providors)

**EDIT:**
 It now seems that the Starter edition is free. (*rushes of to try it*)

Comment: And something like Dropbox will work? Dropbox can map a Folder in any place in any disk. Then you could save your repo there and clone into your working dir. (BTW, I'm talkin' like a mercurial kind of guy, I think)

Comment: Did anyone ever get this to work? It seems that there's a problem with Gladinet Starter complaining something about Rename operation not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You could create SVN repository locally, for example using Visual SVN. Using Windows Live Mesh you can synchronize it with Sky Drive. When you make changes to SVN, you actually making it on local SVN, but because it's synchronized with Sky Drive all changes are immediately visible on Sky Drive folder.

If you work within a team, other team members can also synchronize their local folder with the same folder on Sky Drive, and you can collaborate on the same project. Only difference is that each member is making changes on his local SVN only. Because it's synchronized with Sky Drive, all other members can see changes on their local SVNs. All synchronization is done in background very quick, without user awareness

Comment: This is an outdated topic, but I just wanted to say that today we can achieve similar with Git and Dropbox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively

Answer (score 3):

Might be easier now that Skydrive has Windows integration

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the following:

1. SVN client in build server
2. TeamCity executing a command line build task
3. Skydrive installed in the build server

We use SkyDrive for online back-up purposes in case our server goes down. We have a CI server running TeamCity (This is not a requirement to get it working) that calls a command line that updates a local repository folder in the build server. This repository was created within the local skydrive location.

Skydrive was locally installed using the following installation:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/skydrive/download-skydrive

The client command svn client can be obtained at:
http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion

And the command line to update the repository is:
"c:\PathToSubVersionClient\svn.exe" update --username joe --password bloggs