# android version control mercurial with dropbox if possible

Tags: android, mercurial, development-environment, dropbox

I'm looking into how I could develop on my android tablet and desktop computer. I have all the development tools I need on the android tablet. However there is a few of us that work on these projects. Currently with the the desktops we share a mercurial repos via dropbox. We clone from dropbox locally to work and push changes back to dropbox when done. This would be an ideal solution if I could get it working on my android tablet.

So my question is is there any solution to getting a mercurial repo to clone onto an android device from dropbox or other available folder?

If this is a poor way of working please advise on a better solutions :).

Thanks,

Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should not share repos over dropbox. However, your repo cannot be broken doing it that way. Mercurial has mechanisms to ensure repo integrity to overcome any problems. If it works, it will continue to work. If it is broken, YOU WILL KNOW (that's the main thing).

I can see that Git has a bit better support on android, but Git is way more complicated then Hg, and also does not have push capability at the moment on android.

But, the right way to do it is to use a pc/mac/linux machine like this:

1. use builtin adhoc web server and push/pull between developers directly (no install needed, just some network configuration - if you know each other's IP, you can push/pull)
2. use hosted HgWeb cgi server, also provided by mercurial for central repo
3. use other 3rd party solutions like HgLabs or Rhodecode
4. just use bitbucket

Also, I'm not sure why one would want to develop on android/tablet. However, if someone made me do it, I would hack my tablet, erase android and install Ubuntu Linux on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you host your repositories on Bitbucket (and why not, its free) as well as having access from tortoisehg you can do quite a lot from the online interface including backing out changesets, editing and committing code and files. I've certainly used it a couple of times in emergencies from my Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't share a repository over Dropbox.  It might work fine for a time but has a chance to fail at any time.  Source control needs to be reliable and it is unacceptable to run with such a risk of corruption (IMO).

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967038/501710) for more details.

One thing that you could possibly do for your Android tablet is to use Dropbox to synchronise your *working copy* between your development PC and your Android tablet but I think that you'd have to commit the changes using your PC.  That commit could be done using a remote desktop server and client but you'd need to leave the PC on in order to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into setting up a hosted repository. I think you maybe right in just using dropbox to share between my 2 computers. with it being single user using the dropbox its unlikely to fail. Is there any code control on android that I could use on android? Thanks Dean