# What's the best git installation structure for a one man shop?

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to implement a version control system for my web apps/sites. I am currently working on 3 different machines (2 win and 1 osx) all of which have Dropbox installed. Inside dropbox I have all my webapp projects in a 'websites' folder. This effectively creates a backup of my source code and syncs all 3 computers. However my current version control is duplicating root folders and renaming. I was wondering how could git make my work easier as a one man shop? should I install git on all of my 3 computers? should I install it on my shared hosting service? What do you think would be the best way to implement a version control system under these circumstances?

Also, my source code should remain private.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using dropbox for [synchronizing a bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively) on your 3 computers.

On each of those computer, you can push safely to your local bare repo.
It (the bare repo) get synchronized on the other computers.
You can then, on another computer, pull from the local bare repo (updated).

That being said, [dropbox is not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively/1961529#1961529) the [ideal solution for Git repository sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199637), so synchronizing a [simple bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784) might be less error-prone (and can be done through dropbox or any other file-sharing mean).

Comment: Sounds like this would work fine for a "one man shop" as long as you're mindful to let Dropbox sync before you "push" anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed git using [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/) on dreamhost and it has worked well. My problem was that if I installed it dropbox I couldn't access it easily unless I had dropbox installed on the computer. Which isn't always the case. It also allows me to view my repository through redmine which I also have installed on my shared hosting.