# Multiple remote sources to one main repository in git

Tags: git

I use git and dropbox to keep a record of projects that I am working on in school. I have certain courses that I take each term, but I create a new folder for each of these courses. I back up all the material from these courses with git. I am wondering if there is a way to use the same main repository (eg. the dropbox folder) for multiple source repositories (eg. the local folders for each course.).

The structure would be something like:

`~/Users/Me/dropbox/git --> (main repository)`

`~/Users/Me/Courses/Course_1/. (This is the first course)`
`~/Users/Me/Courses/Course_2/. (This is the second course)`

I want to be able to push from both Course_1 and Course_2 TO the git folder. But, I want to keep them separate so that when I pull from inside Course_2 it doesn't pull all the material from Course_1 as well. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply make one repo per course.
Those would be mirrored by one bare repo per course on Dropbox.

That way, you can clone the course (repo) you need.

That being said, I have seen [issues with bare repo on Dropbox before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309).
I prefer using [Dropbox with git bundles (one file per repo)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633346/6309).

Comment: Yea, I ended up using two different repos. I think that will be easier. Git bundles look pretty great though, so I'll look into those as well.