# Version control on Dropbox vs git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a LaTeX manuscript which I am preparing with my group and are using a shared Dropbox folder. Technically this is version-controlled, but I would like to be able to see diffs of changes you get with a git repository.

Is it possible to create a local git repository to commit to for this reason, without creating a remote repository (since Dropbox kind of serves this purpose already)?

Answer (score 3):

I mentioned [before that using Dropbox for a git repo isn't safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309).
More specifically, the `.git/` folder should not be replicated in dropbox.

That means you can:

- initiate a git repo locally,
- move the `.git` folder *outside* the folder which will contain your files,
- set [environment variable `GIT_DIR`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations) to the .git/ folder path (again moved elsewhere)
- use `git` inside your document folder as usual.
- backup that same document folder (which does not include `.git`) with Dropbox.