# Can I make a single repo git push executable?

Tags: git

Imagine a folder like this

```
Dropbox
-Main folder
--GIT PUSH THE MAGIC REPO.exe
--THE MAGIC REPO
---editor.html
---index.html
```

Can I make a self-contained file that would push the repo even if the machine has no git installed on it nor any system permissions to do so?

Context: I am using GitHub pages and added a visual editor for the website (editor.html) after the non-technical person is done editing the file in local I just want a "PUBLISH" executable for them to hit that executes a git push.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, if your DropBox folder *also* included a Git installation, then you could have a [`post-commit` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7925891/6309) which would execute the push.

But having a [Git repo within a DropBox folder is risky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309).

I would rather delegate the push/publicatio task to a *separate* machine, which would have the same DropBox folder (and Git installed) and would:

- keep the actual Git repo separate from the DropBox folder (the latter including the files, and only the files)
- monitor any changes in that folder: `git --git-dir=/path/to/.git --work-tree=/path/to/DropBox/Folder status`
- on changes, do an add, commit and push.