# Push git project to local directory with a password

Tags: git, cloud-storage

I am currently pushing my project to a local folder that is accessed by Dropbox. That's my backup and safety strategy. I am wondering if I can add another layer of security so that if someone gets a hold of my Dropbox folder, they would have to enter a password to pull the project. That would happen by specifying a password when I am adding a new remote, such as

`~/project $ git remote <some string password> add origin ~/Dropbox/git/project.git`

Is this possible, or am I overthinking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try a put [git bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633346/6309) (one file: a compressed version of your Git repo, one you can clone) in a Dropbox folder.

Putting a full Git repo into Dropbox remains risky, as [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309).

Plus, adding one file means [you can easily encrypt it and add a password](https://superuser.com/q/231868/141).

You can write a script which will:

- create the bundle,
- encrypt it (password-protected)
- push it to the DropBox folder.

Comment: Thank you, this is a near-ideal solution. In the past, I would create a rar-package of the project with a password and put it into Dropbox manually. I didn't know about git bundle, so I will check that out along with the rest of the workflow you pointed out.