# Git-bash makes directories in user folder documents instead of library

Tags: git-bash

Might be confusing. So I have 2 hard drives. All my libraries (Documents, pictures etc.) are on my ssd where Windows is installed. Git bash is also installed on that drive. I was trying to clone a repo from github into my documents but upon going to file explorer and looking in the documents library, it wasn't there.

So I used the explorer's search function to find the repo and it found it. I opened the file's location and it was in my Users folder documents. Now I'm confused because it's as if I have two different documents folders, 1 in my users and then one in my library.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the path provided to `git clone` in your bash session.

Try another approach:

- open a git bash session
- go to the right parent folder
- try and clone there

That is:

```
cd /c/path/to/Document
git clone https://url/remote/name_repo
cd name_repo
```

Comment: Okay I will try the path when I get home from work and see of that works. Originally I was just doing 'CD documents/' and then cloning the repo there

Comment: So the path is apparently taking me to onedrive documents since I have onedrive enabled. How do I stop onedrive from overriding the path?

Comment: @D.Reichardt By selecting which folder you want to synchronize: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/choose-which-onedrive-folders-to-sync-to-your-computer-98b8b011-8b94-419b-aa95-a14ff2415e85. But having a Git repo in a synchronized folder is not always a good idea. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55822571/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309)