# Public git repository

Tags: git, ssh, public-html

Is it possible to have a git repository on a ssh server public? I have an account on a ssh server and want to use it to store a git repository for a project. We work with 2 people on the project but I can't give the other member my password to the account... How can I make sure my team member can push and pull from the repository without knowing my password?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the configuration of the server, you might be able to use git's [smart http](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) transport. If not, you could always use github :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to create another account on the server (one which can only read/write the repository)? Then your colleague you access the server using that account.

I recently found myself in need for a "remote" git repository and used dropbox for it. If you don't need to use that server specifically, maybe this is an option for you as well.

Comment: Dropbox is not a good store for git repos, since it can't handle git metadata conflicts. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199637/is-this-plain-stupid-git-sharing-via-dropbox/5044399#5044399 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Rudi. I haven't really looked at it scientifically, I just use it for some repositories I share with a colleague and never got any problems. I guess I should avoid doing that and properly set up the repos on our server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Read from [Plain SSH server](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#sshserver) to [Gitosis](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#gitosis) and about [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/gl_ssh.html).

For more detailed answer you have to ask more detailed question