# Git on Mac, Windows and Linux, different status

Tags: git, dropbox

I have git installed in my MacBookPro, Windows 7 and a Linux(Slackware) PC

```
Mac:   git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
Win7:  git version 1.9.0.msysgit.0
Linux: git version 1.8.5.5 # I compiled it from source
```

And I have Dropbox installed in all of them to sync a project called, say 'projA'.

When I issue `git status` in `projA`, the results are different:

```
Mac:   clean
Win7:  some files are modified (# but the md5 of these files are all same in three machines.)
Linux: some files are deleted (#and they are really be deleted)
```

What maybe the problem? git? Dropbox?

Comment: Putting your working directory in dropbox is considered harmful.

Comment: Why do you want to use Dropbox to sync your repos instead of using a hosting provider like GitHub or Bitbucket? If you don't want to pay for these services, you can even stick a bare repo on a USB drive and sync your machines that way, because Git accepts file paths as remote repo URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git repositories aren't really meant to be used that way. See this question:

[Is it possible to host a bare Git repository using Dropbox, to share code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199637/is-this-plain-stupid-git-sharing-via-dropbox)

It's safer to take Dropbox out of the equation and use a bare repo on one of your machines, or else use Github or one of its assorted competitors.