# How do I keep GIT repositories inside Dropbox?

Tags: git, github, repository, dropbox

So I've seen similar questions asked before, but I'm not thinking about pushing/pulling from a repo on Git's servers, this is just as a place to keep the repo locally on my machines. I'd still push/pull to GitHub.

I know it can technically live wherever I want it to, but can anyone think of a reason this might end badly?

I use Dropbox on a Mac, Windows system and a Linux server, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Saving a git repository on DropBox etc is not a good idea, and in general, you should try to avoid having a live repository(one whose contents can change frequently) on dropbox. This is because the files within DropBox are synced to the DropBox servers, and can frequently result in corruption of local blobs, which in the worst case can make your repository unusable. For example, check :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/1860929
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5044399/1860929

Since you are already pushing to github, just clone the repository when you need it the next time.

Comment: I had a feeling this was going to be the case. Oh well, now I know. Thanks!

Comment: I want to second this. I didn't have the corruption issue until one of my machines turned to macos and the rest are linux. Now I immediately get corruption after the pushes from macos on all the rest of linux copies of my dropbox directory. not sure why.