# Linking Anaconda to Github in a dynamic way?

Tags: python, github, anaconda

If there a way to link a Python project I am working on in Anaconda to my Github repository in such a way that every time I make changes to my Python project in Anaconda, the changes would be automatically made in my Github repository?

Many thanks.

Comment: Github is not a file syncing service. Use dropdox or google drive for what you are looking to do. You need to learn how to use Git in order to make use of Github

Comment: Do you mean changes in the codebase, or changes in your Anaconda environment itself (i.e. whenever you install a new third party package with `conda install <some-package>`)?

Comment: Need an example of a change you would make in Anaconda that would be reflected in GitHub

Comment: Just codebase changes in my project

Comment: In this case, just use Git to commit changes and push the changes to the GitHub repo. This should be performed manually, because adding meaningful commit messages and keeping track of commit history is the whole point of a VCS such as Git & GitHub. If you don't care for commit history, just use Dropbox or Google Drive as @smac89 suggested, not GitHub. And [be sure not to mix Git with Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199637/is-it-possible-to-host-a-bare-git-repository-using-dropbox-to-share-code), or you might have a bad time.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the input @jfaccioni