# Git Push into Production (FTP)

Tags: git, ftp, push

I would like to know if there is an easy way to push a GIT repository into production (on a FTP server) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Some tools recently added to the [Git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/i/n/t/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools.html):

> [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) by René Moser is a simple
>   shell script for doing FTP the Git
>   way. Use git-ftp.sh to upload only the
>   Git tracked files to a FTP server,
>   which have changed since the last
>   upload. This saves time and bandwith.
>   Even if you play with different
>   branches, git-ftp.sh knows which files
>   are different. No ordinary FTP client
>   can do that.
>
> [git-ftp](http://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp) by Edward Z. Yang is a
>   simple script written in python for
>   uploading files in a Git repository
>   via FTP, only transferring new files
>   and removing old files.

Comment: using git-ftp, is there a way to push just a subdirectory (e.g. the publish folder of html5 boilerplate) to the specified ftp directory?

Comment: And what if there are several developers in the team. Is it still possible to use this scripts?

Comment: @Trilliput : A little late here, but yes, an intermediate server/vm on the network as the place where everyone pushes, and then : https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp#using-a-bare-repository-as-a-proxy

Comment: https://github.com/banago/PHPloy‎ also does a similar thing but works with submodules, which I suspect some of the mentioned tools might struggle with.

Comment: The main problem with git-ftp (not sure script or  python) I tried it was very bad when uploading large chunks of files and long list of files.

Answer (score 14):

If you prefer GUI, use SourceTree, you can easily setup a Custom Action that uses git-ftp mentioned above. A brief description on setup (for Mac) at [Push a Git repository to an FTP](http://eppz.eu/blog/?p=282)

[image]

Comment: @Julix For the article mentioned.

Answer (score 12):

I've found **PHPloy** a great tool for sending your Git commits to remote servers over FTP.  It works from the command-line and is written in PHP (and even detects changes in submodules).

**https://github.com/banago/PHPloy‎**

```
git commit ...
phploy -s staging
phploy -s production
```

Done!

(Disclaimer: after using it for a while I've now contributed some code patches and improvements, making it Windows-compatible.)

Answer (score 10):

If you're on a mac and have Transmit, I'd recommend the following git-tranmit script (https://gist.github.com/379750). It uses DockSend to send only the last updated files. If you're not familiar with DockSend, check out http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/11/15-secrets-of-transmit/.

**Setup:**

1. cp git-transit /usr/sbin/.
2. cd /usr/sbin
3. chmod +x git-transmit
4. Setup drop send for your live app
5. Run git-transmit in your git repository.

Comment: This script is rather clumsy about selecting 'last updated files'. Check out [this fork](https://gist.github.com/quickshiftin/8809435) for a more elegant solution.

Comment: In addition to that you may want to transmit only tracked and uncommited files. Here’s a tiny script which does just that: https://gist.github.com/borisdiakur/37b8f512f6f8865b79c7

Answer (score 5):

That's not what git is for, strictly speaking. However, if your source is something that doesn't need compiling or processing, say a website consisting **entirely** of html and javascript files and the like, you could have a clone of the repo on your webserver and use `git pull` from the server to keep it up-to-date. Note, I would config your webserver to hide the git directory and such. And that's just the beginning of the security concerns.

If you have any sort of compiling or processing, you should start looking at [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [BuildR](http://buildr.apache.org/), [SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/), etc.

Comment: The only problem with this is when you don't have access to the production server, i.e. it might be simple shared hosting, with only FTP access.

Answer (score 5):

You could use **Deployhq.com** it works like a charm, the only thing you need to do is to set up your repository and FTP account.

They currently the following version control systems:

**Git, Subversion, Mercurial.**

With repository hosted

- GitHub
- Bitbucket
- GitLab
- Codebase

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a script in PHP to upload almost automatically the git-diff to a FTP server:

http://code.google.com/p/upload-git-diff-with-ftp/

Answer (score 2):

https://www.deployhq.com/

Free for one project and it works very very well.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Ruby script here - [Ruby git-deploy via FTP or SSH](https://github.com/aizatto/git-deploy) which uploads only the changed files in the git repo via FTP or SSH.

As mentioned in another answer, here is the [Python git-ftp.py script](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp) which does a similar thing.

And here is the shell script version of [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp).

There is also a Ruby gem project called [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) which lets you setup a custom deploy via a git remote using the `git push` command, in the same way as the Heroku and Azure services. For this one you may need to write custom methods to deploy via FTP and I think it assumes you have SSH access to your production server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting code into production, I recommend using an "installer" such as an RPM package to install your code. That way it will be version stamped and you will be able to leverage the installer package to support updates to the production code. Git is not really designed to support production installations, it is intended to track changes to the code itself.

In any event, with an .RPM (or EXE or whatever) built, you can just FTP it to the production system and install it like any other package.

Comment: Well, git can be leverage pretty well for this purpose in reality.  Check out the tag and create post-checkout, post-merge etc hooks to handle any installation procedures needed.  We used to use RPM packages but after moving to git it was simply overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a remote, then you can push to it, however simply pushing code isn't enough, it needs to be merged with the working tree.  The easiest way is to go the other way round, have a working tree on the server and fetch and merge into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to mount the ftp to a local directory using http://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem.

Then you can use it the same way as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively/1961515#1961515).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling a lot to figure out this. I have figured out an easy way to get this done from various sources ([git-ftpINSTALL](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/develop/INSTALL.md),  [git-ftpUPLOAD](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp), [git-ftpIssue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189880/why-am-i-getting-commit-failed-with-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-file), [git-ftpPUSH](http://eppz.eu/blog/git-to-ftp/)). You can read for reference but there is no need because I have mentioned step by step process below.

First thing first: Install git and curl using brew on MAC OS

```
brew install git
brew install curl --with-ssl --with-libssh2
brew install git-ftp
```

Run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp.git
cd git-ftp
git tag # see available tags
git checkout <tag> # checkout the latest tag by replacing <tag>
sudo make install
```

Updating using git

```
git pull
git tag # see available tags
git checkout <tag> # checkout the latest tag by replacing <tag>
sudo make install
```

Setup

```
git config git-ftp.url YourFtpServerName.Net
git config git-ftp.user FtpUserName
git config git-ftp.password YourPassword
```

Upload all files

```
git ftp init
```

Or if the files are already there

```
git ftp catchup
```

Work and deploy

```
echo "Hello StackOverflow" >> index.txt
git commit application/libraries/index.txt -m "I love StackOverflow"
git ftp push
```

If there is an ***error: pathspec 'index.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git***. It means the file hasn't been staged yet, so add the file and then try commit.

```
git add application/libraries/index.txt
git commit application/libraries/index.txt -m "I love StackOverflow"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try FTPloy ...

https://ftploy.com

> "Push changes to GitHub or Bitbucket."
>
> "Deploy Changes automatically to your server"

You have one free project to try it out with. I am currently using for a small php website and it works quite well. A few bugs on the site but its an active project so at least they are working on it.

Comment: I posted this answer prematurely. FTPloy is not quite 'production ready' and there are a lot of bugs. I couldn't get it to work. I am using DeployHQ which works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://gitftp-deploy.com/ if you're on MacOS and you like GUIs.

It is a nice little application that uses Git to track changes and upload only the changed files with FTP.

Especially handy if you don't like paying monthly fees for dozens of smaller projects with small teams.