# Git - Getting the production/staging server to auto-update after pushing to master repo

Tags: git, version-control, branch, staging

I have the following Setup, where Production is running on Windows Server 2003/2008. Master (LAMP lan server) and Production (WAMP remote server) can communicate via a secure VPN-connection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgD4a.png

After a Local Repo pushes to the Master Branch, the Master Repo should push to Production or Production should be triggered to update from Master Repo (bare repo, gold branch or how you like to call it).

Do I need to setup a pushable remote repo on Production, to which the master repo pushes via a post push hook, after some criterias are hit?

additional information

- need to use update - a full clone/export for every release is not possible due to the size of the repo
- no ruby means no capistrano
- phpundercontrol also just clones/export/copys the whole project via (s)ftp which isn't a option for me with a X GB repo
- the whole workflow looks pretty simlilar to nvies git branching model (cannot post url, thx spam protection...)
- [Git Push into Production (FTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950107/git-push-into-production-ftp) could be nasty solution...

Comment: Why do you have a seperate production repo? The branching model explained at http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model does not have a seperate repository for production, it's just branches and tags on one repository.

Comment: The production server has repo cause it need to update from master branch and it can rollback from it's own local history without transfer any files..

Comment: I'll give the following solution a try...  http-based pushing to a apache windows server via git-http-backend.exe http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/comment-page-1/#comment-24958

Answer (score 0):

Just add a post receive hook. Yes, you want a clone on production.