# What technology should I use to automatically update multiple files on multiple ftp projects?

Tags: git, ftp

I would like to build my own tool that updates multiple websites at the same time.

I would probably have 2 config files

1. list of ftp projects(username pass port)
2. list of files I would like to automatically update

I am not sure using a git hook will work as everytime I do an update I would like to pick what files I want to update. But maybe some sort of command/alias triggered from the terminal can do the job.

Any ideas on where to start?

Thank you

Comment: You could look at `scp` and cron jobs if you are using linux. You could certainly write a script to `scp` to copy a new version of file and overwrite the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I've built this tool called [PHPloy](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy) that does exactly that - deploys files through FTP by asking Git which files where changed last. Very simple to use:

```
phploy --server production
```

There are also several other similar tools that you can find check out here: [Deploy a PHP project from Git to a server that does not have Git installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070147/deploy-a-php-project-from-git)