# Can we use github as hosting for any static html website?

Tags: github

I want to create a website with zero hosting charges. Can we use github as hosting for any static html website?

Comment: Git is a version control tool. You install it on your computer and then you can do version control on files. Using it as hosting makes no sense.

Comment: No, you can't, the question makes no sense. Use GitHub pages, or google "free web hosting".

Comment: I use github, but that's not "git".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333503/using-git-with-shared-hosting-plan

Answer (score 1):

Git is a version control system for managing file versions, among other things.

This has **nothing to do** with hosting a website. It's like you'd me how you could use `paint` to host your website.

So **no**, you can't use git to host your website.

---

Maybe you meant `github` ? If so, please ask a new question and use the correct terms. Also, please search stackoverflow if a question like that has already been asked.