# Deploying to FTP directly with a `git push`?

Tags: git, deployment, ftp

I'm wondering if I can configure a remote FTP branch in git so that I can just push to github and then push to deployment right after one another.

If I could, this would be awesome.

Otherwise, what other options are there for quick and easy deployment?  Can git use ssh or anything like that?  My host is SDF.org, and you can see the options they offer to validated users here: `http://sdf.org?join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using another approach for deployment of my files over ssh/ftp: instead of using a git push, I pack the wanted files as a `.tar.gz` archive and upload that using `scp` or the corresponding ftp commands. See 
[the section "The Hook"](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~mamuelle/blog/introduction.html) in my blog entry. There, I find all wanted files using `find` and pack them using tar:

```
find . -name "*.html" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" | tar -czf archive.tgz --files-from -
```

After doing that, you can simply upload the file using `scp` and unpack with a command over `ssh`:

```
scp archive.tgz mamuelle@g<domain>:~/.public_html/
ssh mamuelle@<domain> tar xfz .public_html/archive.tgz -C .public_html
```

You can do the same thing using ftp. Check out the corresponding manual on how to upload files to ftp.

What I described above can be started automatically using hooks. I use it with `post-merge`, for example.

Another option is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950107/git-push-into-production-ftp). There are simple shell scripts to upload a file via `git-push`.

**edit** With ssh, you can also directly push to a bare remote repository.