# Git pull without SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm using MochaHost as hosting, which does not include SSH access (unbelievable).
The problem is that I'm using Git for most of my projects now, and I need to deploy them in the hosting.

Tech support says there's no way to get SSH access with them.
Changing the hosting company is not an option right now, since I still have 2.5 years left with them already paid.

Is there any way or workaround to clone/pull a Git repo without SSH access?
FTP is an option, but it misses the entire point of Git.

Comment: Which repo host are you using? For example, Github projects often offer an HTTP address as well as SSH.

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950107/git-push-into-production-ftp

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll try all these options. Any of them must work. I'll let you know.
@neontapir I'm using Bitbucket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you read the [Git url options in the official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a)? You can use a number of different protocols besides ssh with Git:

> Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp, and ftps can be used for fetching and rsync can be used for fetching and pushing, but these are inefficient and deprecated; do not use them).
>
> The following syntaxes may be used with them:
>
> - `ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ftp[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`