# How to clone github private repository in cpanel (shared host without terminal or ssh)?

Tags: github, ssh, cpanel

I have a shared host and they don't give me `ssh` or terminal for it.
I've tried to clone my private repos from git by Git™ Version Control so I am using `ssh` link because they need permission. I don't know how to make `ssh` key on `cpanel` so I can make it from my mac and upload to `cpanel` and also add to Github.

But when running, they give me error: `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`.

I'm a beginner for using Git & StackOverflow, so please let me know if there's anything wrong with the question I've asked. Thanks!

Tried Url with password
[Cloning a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo) and 
having a response "`The clone URL cannot include a password.`"

Comment: you should check these answers:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950107/git-push-into-production-ftp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107431/git-pull-without-ssh

Comment: Thanks you for that! Maybe I will try another way. All of them can't using in my solution.

Comment: @HùngNguyễn I have this same question, were you able to work around it?

Comment: @Guy I changed shared host to VPS. I can't find anyway for sharedhost (with limit permission).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was finally able to do it by SSH'ing in through an external client (PuTTY, in my case) and then following the steps to give a private key to my repo.

You should put what worked for you in an answer so others can be helped by it.

Answer (score 1):

This is different than what worked for the OP (hopefully they put their solution in an answer here).

I was able to solve this problem by installing an external SSH client (like [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) for Windows) and then SSH into my website using its IP address. Then I followed [these steps](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/) from cPanel to connect the private repository.