# Why am I getting "Commit failed with error: pathspec ... did not match any file(s)"?

Tags: git, git-commit

I am having some issues with Git.

I have a repository where I can commit any file to without problem. However, there is a single file 'Funder.php' which, when I try committing, tells me there is an error  as:

```
Commit failed with error:
pathspec 'application/libraries/Funder.php' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I am quite new to this, so was wondering if anybody could please help?

Comment: Does the file `application/libraries/Funder.php` exist? What OS are you using?

Comment: Try running `git status` in your repository and see if you get any clues to way this is happening.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is the error you get when you attempt to run

```
git commit <file>
```

but `<file>` hasn't been staged yet; in other words, Git hasn't been told about it, yet. This is most likely what's happening here. Run

```
git add application/libraries/Funder.php
```

then try to commit.

Answer (score 54):

The reason why this error happens is pointed in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29485441/2769415

> Windows’ file system is mostly case-insensitive, so you cannot rename
>   a file by just changing its capitalization. Instead, you will have to
>   use a temporary name in between.

Solution:
Rename the file back to the original one, then rename it to a different name, then back to the one with the correct capitalization. Git will not throw the bug anymore.

Example:

```
Created FOOBar class.
Renamed it to FooBar and then got the error.
Rename it back to FOOBar.
Rename to FooBarTest.
Rename to FooBar.
Git works now.
```

Comment: This worked after trying and failing with the above solutions.

Comment: Does it count as a bug in git?

Comment: @ZhangMeng - it's more of a user error than a bug, but perhaps a UX feature. See [my concise answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34427057/1799146) that points to the issue and how to resolve quickly without this random renaming game

Comment: what if i don't remember its old name?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in Android Studio after renaming some activities. I tried adding (git add) and moving (git mv) the files but never helped and I was getting the same message again and again.

Finally I decided to backup the classes in the package that had the problematic file in a separate folder in my HDD, then I removed the files from the original folder and in the terminal I did:

```
rm app/src/main/java/com/path/to/package/with/problematic/files/
```

Then recreated the deleted package via Android Studio and copied and pasted my classes back there. After that I was able to commit without any issues.

Comment: That's a pretty drastic solution for just one file.

Comment: I'm facing same problem. What can i do for whole project ?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a concise answer on the quickest way to resolve this issue. Similar to @cmbind55 post but to the point.

**Problem:** I have added a file that I later renamed.

**Solution:**

1. Un-add the old file name

`git reset HEAD oldFileName.file`

2. Now, add the new file name

`git add newFileName.file`

3. Commit and be happy

Comment: I added a directory like Dir in my project structure which wasn't commited to the git, now if try to rename it to dir it throws above error!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar sounds like you may have done `git add` to a file under Dir. Git won't track empty directories, so you probably have something inside Dir that git is tracking. What does your output say?

Comment: Julian you are right indeed i did copied some files and folders inside Dir but i deleted them rather than committing! Which means my working directory doesn't have any changes to be committed because i have already deleted the files & folders! P.S: I'm a newbie to git :)

Comment: Strangest part is that Android studio doesn't show any files & folders that are to be committed in LocalChanges tab! But on git shell if i run `git status` i can still see the a lot of files that are not staged for commit and a lot files that are (deleted files and folders) to be committed!

Comment: I definitely recommend learning git at the command line first before using the tools. Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 4):

if working from terminal ensure that you have a message flag in your command.

`git commit "Your Commit Message" //Throws an error: pathspec '3.`

`git commit -m "Your Commit Message" //No error thrown`

Comment: This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this failing commit scenario due to a renamed directory.

This was the originally created directory with a capitalization mistake:

```
application/Templates/lists/index.html
```

Within the IDE, I had agreed to add this file to the existing git repo.
In later testing, I discovered I had a case-sensitive path issue with the capitalization of "Templates".  Within the IDE, I simply renamed the directory to "templates" (changed to lower-case).  I did not record the actual sequence of events around this, but later when my commit failed with the following message, I had a hunch this was this issue.  Apparently, the IDE did not fully handle this case of renaming a directory.

The IDE commit error message:

> Commit failed with error: pathspec
>   "application/templates/lists/index.html" did not match any file(s)
>   known to git.

After doing some reading, my strategy was to take the file back out and then add it again.  I unstaged the suspect file

```
git reset HEAD lists/Templates/lists/index.html
```

Note, git status only showed the directory here... Not the file.

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    lists/templates/
```

Then, I added back with the corrected directory name (I only used the path for the add, following the lead from git status).

```
git add lists/templates/
```

After this, my commit succeeded.  I'm not sure if this was the ideal technique, but it resolved the commit error in my case.

Answer (score 3):

i had same problem. just change 'Initial comment single quotes '' to double quotes ""

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but fixed it. I should have been using "" instead of '' in windows command line

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. None of the answers here did not help me to resolve the issue. After being stuck for two days, I drew attention that the whole filename with path are very long. I did refactoring renaming it to something less complicated and rearranging folders to reduce the full filename length and it worked!

Comment: Wow, this was it for me too. Running on windows, of course, where paths have problems with long names.

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled**

Ran into this while changing "contents.json" file for my LaunchImage asset catalog.  You may elect to use the terminal commands provided as the answer, but try this simpler way...

**Source Control -> Refresh Status**

[image]

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @MJQZ1347 hey could you please add to what condition you are trying to resolve exactly?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen Great!  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with the word "certificate" as a package name... when i rename the Package to "certificates" it just work... strange ..

Answer (score 0):

With XCode 7.3 I renamed the file in question to FooBar.foo.tmp and then commited once XCode/git added this new file and set the old one to be deleted. Once I commited then I renamed it back (within XCode). Now it's fine. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was copy / pasting the entire commit line, and it had special characters, which appeared to be normal characters in the console (ex:  smart quotes instead of normal quotes).  Once I pasted them into a plain-text editor, I saw them, corrected them, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with '.entitlements' file, deleting existing file and adding it again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem committing deleted files with SourceTree in Mac. 
One of the problematic files had accents (áéíóú...). To solve it I had to use terminal rather than SourceTree

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this by mistakenly creating the branch in a different repo on BitBucket, so make sure you're in the right repo and that the branch exists there.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I was passing the commit message as part of command line argument. The commit message I was passing with double quotes.

In git commit I was using double quotes again. This was throwing the same error.

So I removed the double quotes from the commit message while calling git commit. This fixed my issues.

```
git commit -m "%commit_message%"
```

The above command was throwing the same error

I have changed it to

```
git commit -m %commit_message%
```

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the troublesome file was marked with `--skip-worktree`. This could be easily checked with

```
git ls-files -v . | grep ^S
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a temporary word backup file starting with ~$, the filename was ~$?????.docx.

I am not sure what was going on - my word document is picked up by GIT using Pycharm so I guess I was editing at somepoint when working with GIT.

I had to create a temporary file with the same name, commit then delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using double quotes for "Initial project version"
```

try using double quotes, if you are work on Windows OS