# Can't Commit After Upgrading Android Studio

Tags: git, github, android-studio

I upgraded my **AS** from **'1.2'** to **'1.3'**, and now I want to commit the changes I made and I get this error:

```
Error:pathspec 'app/src/main/java/com/blahblah' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Can anyone save me?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was...it was not related to upgrading Android Studio.
I refactored and change the name of one of my classes, only changing it to lowercase from uppercase.
But looks like GIT has problem with that: [Git case-sensitivity error -- renaming and committing from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485350/git-case-sensitivity-error-renaming-and-committing-from-android-studio)

So it basically deleted my old file, and when I wanted to push the new one, it would not let me...had to revert back to my previous commit, and change the name as the above post mentions. Weird weird stuff.