# Git - Android Studio no longer lets me commit changes and push to GitHub

Tags: android, git, android-studio

As of a couple of hours ago, Android Studio no longer lets me commit my changes. When the Commit dialog pops up, it shows the files that have changed and lets me enter a commit message. However, when i click Commit (or Commit and Push), the progress dialog comes up, goes to about 10% - 20% and then just disappears without actually committing anything. If i try again (without restarting the IDE first), nothing seems to happen at all when i click Commit/Commit and Push.

Sadly, Google searches have so far not been very helpful to me, so if any of you could help me out, i would really appreciate it.

I have heard, however, that git might sometimes clash with Windows on changing the capitalization of file names. I do remember renaming my `Utilities` package to `utilities` and `Adapters` package to `adapters`. Could this be causing my problem and if so, how can i fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by LaYer Sutachad, I attempted to Commit and Push with "Perform code analysis" unchecked in the Commit dialog. This, however, finally gave me a bunch of actual error messages in the form of:

`Commit failed with error:
pathspec 'f/Workspaces/AndroidStudio/ProjectName/app/src/main/java/com/ project/Utilities/PixelConverter.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

After only a few Google Searches I found an answer to this problem provided by RacZo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190273/4119127). Which basically prompts to backup the problematic packages/files and re add them through Android Studio, adding them to Git in the process.

Thanks to LaYer Sutachad for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 87):

I have the same problem.
Try uncheck "Perform code analysis" in commit changes dialog. it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try when i get the chance. Are you aware of any dangers or side effects of unchecking "Perform code analysis"?

Comment: It didn't work right away, but i managed to solve it from there on out myself. I have posted an explanation below as an answer.

Comment: Wow.. that was it.. i spent 8 hours today trying to figure this out :(

Comment: Technically this works. But can anybody explain what are the risks or what assumes the uncheck of the "Perform code analysis" ?!

Comment: It really works but why? :| how someone must guess this?!

Comment: This worked for me, will check files on github to verify.

Comment: You deserve a beer :)

Comment: @LaYer You´re a lifesaver man. Android SDK guys should really check this thing out...

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from same problem. Initially i unchecked **"Perform code analysis"** in commit changes dialog. but it didn't worked for me so kept it as unchecked and proceed with **"Invalidate cache & restart"** from studio setting then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Perform code analysis** can be turned it off in the **Settings/Preferences dialog ⌘,** go to **Version Control | Commit**