# Problems in pushing to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github

I am following the [tutorial](https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-tutorial) to build a bot. Steps 7 says:

```
git init
git add .
git commit --message 'hello world'
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

However when I execute git commit --message 'hello world', I get the following error message error:

pathspec 'world'' did not match any file(s) known to git.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting “Commit failed with error: pathspec … did not match any file(s)”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28189880/4133798)

Answer (score 0):

run `git status` on that folder. if there are no files staged for commit it may be the problem