# How does `receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead` interact with the Index?

Tags: git, git-push, git-config, git-index

The `receive.denyCurrentBranch` [config option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) controls what happens if you push to a repo's branch that is checkout.

By default, it rejects it (which is why you usually only push to bare repos, which have no checkout branches).

It can be disabled via `ignore` or `warn`.

Another option is `updateInstead`.

What this does is that if the `HEAD` and working directory are the same, and the branch being pushed is `HEAD`, both the working directory and the branch/`HEAD` are updated at the same time.

If the working directory is different from `HEAD`, the push is rejected.
This is useful, for pushing to webservers, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34696660/1172541).

My question is, does this option interact with the [Index](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) at all?

Is the Index updated? What if `HEAD` and the working directory match, but not `Index`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is the Index updated? What if HEAD and the working directory match, but not Index?

[Commit 0855331 (git 2.4.0-rc0, Dec. 2014)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0855331941b723b227e93b33955bbe0b45025659) states it clearly:

> When `receive.denyCurrentBranch` is set to `updateInstead`, a push that
>   tries to update the branch that is currently checked out is accepted
>   only when the index and the working tree exactly matches the
>   currently checked out commit, in which case **the index and the
>   working tree are updated to match the pushed commit**.
>   Otherwise the push is refused.

Although that same commit introduced the `push-to-checkout` hook.

> This hook can be used to customize this "push-to-deploy" logic.
>   The hook receives the commit with which the tip of the current branch is going to be updated, and **can decide what kind of local changes are acceptable and how to update the index and the working tree to match the updated tip of the current branch**.

That gives a bit of flexibility regarding the index.

---

[Commit 1a51b52, git 2.4.0-rc2, Apr 2015](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a51b52422e055e433dec9a496621341d70d38ff) says it again:

> Setting `receive.denycurrentbranch` to `updateinstead` and pushing into
>   the current branch, when the working tree and the index is truly
>   clean, **is supposed to reset the working tree and the index to match
>   the tree of the pushed commit**.