# git error : ssh: Could not resolve hostname?

Tags: git, cygwin, github

ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly ?

ive set up a git repo useing --bare ( i even dont know what it mean )
im following the [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively) and when i do

```
$ git clone C:\Users\DAMS\Documents\My Dropbox\Projects\RED.git
```

or

```
$ git clone C:/Users/DAMS/Documents/My Dropbox/Projects/RED.git
```

even this ( diffrent error )

```
$ git clone /C/Users/DAMS/Documents/My Dropbox/Projects/RED.git
fatal: Could not switch to '/C/Users/DAMS/Documents': No such file or directory
```

it somehow give me a error. ( btw im useing cygwin on windows )

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$ git clone "/cygdrive/c/Users/DAMS/Documents/My Dropbox/Projects/RED.git"
```

You're not escaping the space in "My Dropbox", which splits the content into multiple argunemts to git. using the c: specification causes it to use ssh to access a host called 'c'

Answer (score 1):

the colon is used to separate hostname from the path.

i believe in cygwin you can say: /c/users/DAMS/…

```
 $ git clone '/c/Users/DAMS/Documents/My Dropbox/Projects/RED.git'
```

Comment: $ git clone /c/Users/DAMS/Documents/My Dropbox/Projects/RED.git
fatal: Could not switch to '/c/Users/DAMS/Documents': No such file or directory :| , anyway thanks for the replay

Comment: @Adam: You have to either quote the entire argument, or escape the spaces with `\`

Comment: That should have been a backslash, strange.