# are there any Free or Value for Money (VFM) Private Git Repo with Collaborator?

Tags: git, repository

I am looking for a free or VFM Git Private Repository, with at least 4 Private Collaborator or User. So far I've found some free private repos & users. But none are having more than 4 private user.

List of Free Git Private Repository with Private User

1. [Github](http://github.com)

   - Free: 0 user
   - Micro: 1 user
   - Note:

     - [Git Edu](https://github.com/edu) (I get my free micro upgrade here. But only for 1 private collaborator)
2. [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com)

   - Free: 2 users
3. [ProjectLocker](https://www.projectlocker.com)

   - Free: 3 users

Does Anyone have found any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the **Bitbucket** if you have a collaborator up to 5 users. It is also allow unlimited private repository. And you can host git and hg.

Alternatively, use **Dropbox** for more freedom. You've stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6890488/1221540)

Another way, if you want it to reside on your server, then you may **create your own**. You can [Google it.](http://www.google.com.sg/search?as_q=setup%20git%20server). And you need to make your server accessible in the public.

Answer (score 1):

**[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)**

Previously it only support mercurial, but now it support Git also.
It support unlimited private repo, up to 5 Users for free.
So this should be my choice at the time being.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Github Small with 5 collaborators.

Comment: but it's not free.
For micro plan in github, We can get it free from GitEdu. How about small plan? any way to get it free or cheaper? :)

Comment: You said "value for money". As i understand this phrase, it says, that something costs money, but you get the adequate value. From my experiences, this is valid for Github.

Comment: Oh, Alright,... Any other alternatives which might be cheaper or possibly free than github for collaboration?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we can actually use Dropbox as our Git Repository. This might be a good option for those who want a private repository and collaborator for free.

Dropbox is free yet we can host our git repository to collaborate with our peers in private.

We create a git bare repos in Dropbox, push your project code to the dropbox and share it to your peers. Later your peers will clone it from his dropbox directory.

To find out more how to
[Use Git in Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively)

But there are  some problem with this technique. When you and your peers push at the same time, the repos may clash. Solution would be to inform your peers not to push while you're pushing code.

So with a team of 4 or less, I think it shouldn't be a big issue using Dropbox as Git repository. What do you think?