# Rails App in Dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

I would like to backup my rails app usig a private git repo. I've decided to use Dropbox but I've already deployed to heroku, setup DNS for a custom domain name without backing up and would hate for something to go wrong by transferring my project.

Does anyone have experience with this or knows if something will go wrong? Should I reconfigure any files before transferring to a private dropbox folder?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively

Comment: I've had git give me errors, probably caused by race conditions, on a git project in Dropbox. If you want to use Dropbox for backup, it's probably better to just copy the project into it instead of pulling / pushing from Dropbox. That said, none of the errors I've had were fatal, just commands aborting because a file couldn't be opened.

Comment: titaniumdecoy Thanks but I was specifically worried about how heroku would react and that's not mentioned in that post. Inerdia I may copy like you suggested, although I just tested on a sample app connected to heroku and nothing crazy happened, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's addons (i.e. custom domain) configurations are located on their server, not on your computer. Typically configs appear in ENV variables. Type `heroku config` to see what you have.

So yes, you are free to copy your code anywhere you like, and be sure to copy your dotfiles as well.

Personally, I use github for my code backups.

Comment: Thanks! I was specifically worried about heroku. Tried it on a test app and everything transferred smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

bitbucket now has private git repos. Unfuddle had them for a while too. These are all free, BTW.

Comment: Thanks I'll consider them in the future, I hope they continue offering free private repos

Comment: Unfuddle has been free for a number of years. Bitbucket has started this within the last month.

Answer (score 0):

In short - don't reconfigure or setup anything - have fun of some coding instead :)
If you just want your repo to stay safely in the "cloud" then:

1. Bundle (for git or mercurial)
2. Gmail the bundle to yourself as a reply to the same "pull" message". Or, in case you have a fellow coder, then gmail to him/her. Double-backup.
3. Done and forgotten. There is plenty of room in you gmail inbox and sent-items for the source-code of several projects.

IMHO it is:

- fast
- platform-neutral
- shareable via smart-phone within 5 minutes maximum
- pull/push/work anywhere
- secure
- easy
- a natural habit