# Using Dropbox to sync source code, with git

Tags: git, version-control, dropbox

I am a single developer, who uses multiple computers to work on a project. Sometimes it would be nice to just share the project via Dropbox, rather then having someone clone/push/pull. Often times these people are designers and others who are not technically inclined to even use git.

In addition to sharing it with others easily, I could knock out some code on one computer, switch to another, then commit. Often times I don't want to commit and pull so often (I switch between laptop and desktop often).

So is it okay to throw an entire project on Dropbox with an existing VCS in place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively

https://gist.github.com/magicseth/1951984

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5558822

Comment: Wonderful - looking at the YC link, the idea seems to get mixed reactions, although for many it works really well. I will post back here after I use it to share how to use it effectively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropbox and git, could it cause conflicts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226256/dropbox-and-git-could-it-cause-conflicts)