# Git and Dropbox - local repo

Tags: git, backup, synchronization, dropbox, data-consistency

I have read noumerous threads and watched many videos on combining Dropbox and Git functionality.
One such thread is this: [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively)

Here is what i want to do:

- I am currently working on a large personal project (only me, no need for encryption).
- Work is done on two desktop computers (Win 7, Ubuntu) and one laptop (OSx).
- I wish to have my files accesible from anywhere and under version control (git)
- It would be great to have web-access to all the files (trough Dropbox.com), so there would be no need to install Git if I were to eg. borrow a computer.

Most of the guides use Dropbox to house the **remote** repo. This is OK, but then one has to install git on every computer to access the files, an there would be no direct file access via web.

Currently i have my files and the local repo in Dropbox (yes, I am aware of the size issue), and a remote repo on the schools ssh server.
The idea is that i can choose to work on any computer (even without committing), and still be able to use computer #2 or #3 to continue work and commit from there. Overall backup is on the ssh server.

Any thoughts on this setup would be greatly appreciated. If anyone has a better idea, please let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

I really don't think Dropbox is a good solution for this. For what you want, I would probably `git clone` to a USB stick and carry that around.

Barring that, all the online git hosts that I know of (github, etc) allow you to download a tarball of whatever commit, and many of them allow you to edit files in-place.

Comment: Thanks, but a USB stick is not a viable option. I need to move from one OS to another in minutes to run software and simulations. EDIT: How about this: Use GIT in the "intended" way with a central repo on the SSH server and local on other machines. Then symlink ONE of the machines local repo to a Dropbox folder?

Comment: I don't see how a clone on a USB stick prevents you from doing that. That said, when I need to test in multiple environments, I use vms.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. Yes, that is possible, but i wish to regard it as the second option for now. I have had too many negative issues with vms i am afraid.. Both Linux on Win and vice versa tends to hang using VitualBox or WMware when disconnecting external displays from a laptop.

Comment: I would, in all honesty, prefer having to remember to take a vm snapshot before removing a display than using Dropbox in this manner.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback @jeremiahd. Perhaps github can meet my demands. I have to investigate that a bit more.