# Source code backup strategy

Tags: version-control, backup

I have a "Projects" folder which contains dozens of Visual Studio projects. I want to create a backup for them. First I thought I should copy them all to my SkyDrive or DropBox folders and let them be synced to the cloud whenever there is a change.

The other strategy would be using a source control but I don't want the backup to take place whenever a change is made and it should be optimized. By that I mean, only the changed files and only the changed parts should be uploaded to the server to save my bandwidth. I don't have a very good connection (512 Kbps).

Also my codes are very valuable for me so security is very important to me.

Is there a way to achieve the automatic backup to the cloud (ideally free) and take advantage of the source control options (such as revisions, etc.)?

I'm sure a lot of people have solutions for this and a lot of people have the same problem so please let the question be answered instead of just clicking "close"!

Answer (score 1):

Use GitHub or BitBucket. You have all the benefits of version control and a cloud storage for your repositories.

You can commit changes as often as you like, and only need traffic when you push or pull changes to or from the server. The version control systems are smart enough to sent only the modified files.

You could even have a team working on a local network, without the need of a cloud solution and only push to the cloud server periodically just for backup. To do that, you can create a script that pulls from your local repository and pushes to the server. That script can be run in a scheduler.

Apart from the service used to backup your files, I think you should use version control anyway. As a programmer I don't think you can live without.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. If you want your repositories to be private, you can host an unlimited number for free at Bitbucket as long as no more than 5 users are accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

[This might be of interest to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively)

The idea is that you create just the Source Control repository in Dropbox, and check out an actual copy onto your machine.

You could then only commit (which would trigger the sync) the files you've modified, and that was also reserve all of your history for those projects.