# Github and Dropbox conflict risk?

Tags: github, dropbox

I have a dev folder with all my projects. Some of these are on github and some are not. I also use Dropbox (with symlinks) to keep my data synchronised across several computers.

For example if I add something to my Documents folder on one PC I can then see it in the corresponding folder on another PC.

My question is: If I do the same with my dev folder (so the dev folder is synced by Dropbox on both PCs) will it cause problems with my pushing to github?

Comment: Obviously because I don't want to try something which has the potential to wreak havoc on important data.

Comment: I meant with a test repo

Comment: @Jayraj I fear that it might work with a simple test repo and then develop a serious problem on a different OS for instance, it's hard to do an extensive test and I'm sure somebody has tried this. Surprisingly there is little information on the internet about this scenario that I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't **ever** want to mix code versioning strategies.  Either all of your code lives in git (which is a good idea), or it all lives in Dropbox (which doesn't give you any history, hence a ***very bad*** idea).

When you add a source file to git, you *should* be forced to push it to Github so it can be pulled at a later date.

I get the feeling that you will run into issues when pushing the code - you'll be adding new files in through one source, but pulling through another - it'd turn into a headache more than a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you could "prove" that is ok. But, I have used exactly this development model with no issues. I personally, don't use symlinks in my dropbox but that shouldn't affect anything. All of my git repos are on my Dropbox. I've been working this way for over a year across OXS, Windows, and Ubuntu. All of my commits and pushes have worked just fine.

Also, this may be a repeat of this question: [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively)

[edit:]

Actually one thing was recently brought to my attention is that you might run into an issue with line endings across systems. This post from GitHub (with a link back to an SO question) explains how to deal with line endings.

Comment: Thanks, great to hear that! I think it's not a duplicate as my question is much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and now my answer is "**simply move your repository out of Dropbox**".

As you can see, [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively) is not the same question, but if you just search the key word "GitHub", you will see the debate about your confusing. And maybe you will make your own desition.