# Uploading CSV file to my Github automatically

Tags: csv, github

I have a .CSV file in my Google Drive that every 10 miunets it will update. Is it possible to send it to my Github repository automatically whenever it is updating?

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you have Google Drive installed?

Answer (score 1):

From this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947502/can-i-push-pull-directly-from-my-google-drive-online) it is hard or impossible **without** third party applications.

If you want to use the third party applications, try...

- https://github.com/ncw/rclone
- https://github.com/odeke-em/drive
- https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/google-drive/
- Or Google "sync github with google drive"

Note: I have not used or support any of the applications.