# Storing git-synced folder in Dropbox

Tags: git, github, dropbox

Is it safe to create a github repository and store that folder in dropbox? A bit redundant, but this is the state of my current workflow.

Comment: Check "Using Git and Dropbox together effectively" question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively/

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, even though it'll be redundant. I did this a few months ago, and had no problems with it.
If Dropbox sync causes your local and remote repositories to diverge, you can always do a rebase / merge using Git, or look through the Dropbox history. This is because Git doesn't actively try to keep the folder in sync (like Dropbox does); only when you execute Git commands (e.g. push, pull)

Comment: The way I see it, I have the folder in my Dropbox to sync between my laptop and my desktop. It's a pages branch, so I don't want to have to push every little change I make as my site won't be finished yet.

Comment: You should be fine then, if you're just using Dropbox to keep your laptop and desktop in sync between commits.