# Local git repository using Windows 7 with XAMPP server

Tags: php, windows, git

I am working on a project configured on Windows 7 machine. I am the only developer working on it, so I want to setup a private Git repository on the same machine and want to work by creating git branches. Can anyone let me know how can I create git repository with my current system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't yet installed git on your Windows machine, get the latest version from [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win)

You can create a git repository on local machine and clone it on the same machine.
But I would suggest you to host your code on server, so there are less chances of loosing your hard-work.

There are many free code hosting sites for Git and some of them also provide private repositories. I use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for my projects.

There is another option for private repositories which is Git on Dropbox,
This answer here will help you with this: [using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961515).

If you decide to create a repository only on local machine, then here are the steps,

```
mkdir /c/GIT
cd /c/GIT/
git init --bare myproject.git

cd /c/xampp/www/myproject/
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin /c/GIT/myproject.git
git push -u origin master
```

Now, you can start working on your project in C:\xampp\www\myproject\ folder.

To create and switched to a new branch use,

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

which is shorthand for

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
```

Comment: cool.. this is working for me but how can i fetch lasted code from origin... i used git fetch origin but it throwing error

Comment: you can use `git pull <remote> <branch>` or `git fetch <remote> <branch>` depending upon your choice. Check 'Working with the code' section on [Git info] (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone the directory , If you want to create the git repo locally only. In order to create a new git repository use 'git init 'command.

Comment: and one more thing XAMP server has nothing to do with your git repository or any other operation relating to git