# Use Git and Box.com together effectively

Tags: git, webdav, box

How do I use git and [box.com](https://www.box.com//) together effectively? When I try to create a bare repository on box.com mounted with davfs2 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), I get errors of the form `error: could not commit config file` and many of the directories and files I expect to be there have zero length. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960799/238405) and the answers show how to use Dropbox in this way; can I do this on Box?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question definitively (I'm not a Box.com user), but note that Dropbox operates in a completely different fashion: it stores files in a *local* directory on your system, and then syncs this with the Dropbox servers.  Unlike what you have described, Dropbox does not perform any sort of remote mount, using DAV or otherwise.

It is likely that `davfs2` does not support enough of the POSIX filesystem interface to make git happy; using a tool like `strace` you could probably figure out what exactly is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I suspect you will have a lot of difficulty using a mounted FS that connects to Box.com directly. Git works well with Dropbox due to what larsks points out, namely that it basically syncs a local directory.

Switch your Box client to a non-filesystem-mounting solution such as:

https://github.com/noiselabs/box-linux-sync

And it should work without any problems, since it will just be syncing a local directory instead of directly reading and writing to the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I notice on the link you provide that box-linux-sync requires davfs2. So it seems this must also mount the filesystem, but perhaps always works on a local copy, then makes sure the two are in sync? If so I could see how that would solve the problem.