# How can you transparently link a Dropbox folder with a Git repo?

Tags: git, dropbox

In my application, users have text files that are kept in sync and versioned using Git.  Whenever the user starts a session, my application clones their repo, and when the user signs out, my application commits and pushes their changes, all under the hood.

I am now interested in giving users the ability to sync their files with their Dropbox account.  For example, whenever they make a change to a file in my application, that change should be synced to Dropbox.  Likewise, if they were to change a file in Dropbox, that change should end up as a commit in my Git server.

For Git --> Dropbox, I can easily enough set up a hook that automatically uploads changes to Dropbox whenever there is a Git commit.

How could I implement Dropbox --> Git?  Is there a solution that's better than polling the Dropbox API for changes at a set interval or user action?  Is there some other way I can implement bidirectional file transfer between Dropbox and Git?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively

Comment: @punitvara That question is unrelated to the one that I asked here.

Comment: Okay I was just try ting to help. No problem :-) I will look for other solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [webhooks](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks).