# Creating a local git repository instead of using github

Tags: git

I know that in project x you can do `git init` but what about creating a place to push too locally? So for example I use drop box and I want to create a git repo there that I can do `git push drop-box`

I did: `git init --bare` in the drop box folder and then tried doing:

```
git add remote origin "/Users/Adam/Documents/rpg maker/the-child-and-the-poet-repo/"
fatal: /Users/Adam/Documents/rpg maker/the-child-and-the-poet-repo/: '/Users/Adam/Documents/rpg maker/the-child-and-the-poet-repo/' is outside repository
```

But as you can see this didn't work. **Ideas?**

Comment: Have you seen [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively)?

Comment: you have transpositioned the arguments `remote` and `add`

Answer (score 0):

The link I provided in the comment above is the way to go for DropBox, but I thought it might be useful to have a more general set of instructions for creating a local Git repository, so here it is.

You can initialize a local Git repository with just three commands.  From your `C:/` drive (on Windows) type:

```
mkdir newrepo.git
cd newrepo.git
git init --bare
```

Now you can clone a copy of your local repository to another local location:

```
git clone C:\newrepo.git newrepo
```

The `git clone` command will clone `newrepo` into a directory called `/newrepo`.  It will initialize a `.git` directory inside of it, and pull down the entire repository content.  In addition, it will check out a working copy (usually `master`), and this is the branch on which you will begin.

You are now ready to start working, and all the usual Git commands are fair game from this point forward.

Please have a look at [this great blog](https://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/creating-local-git-repositories-yeah-its-that-simple/) for more information.