# Syncing Git repo to Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gitpython

So suppose I have a git repository `https://github.com/jc/` 
and I have a location for the google bucket `gs://acme-sales/`.

Is there a way to write a python program which updates the changes which have been made in github and sync them to google cloud each time we run it?

I suppose we have to use `gitpython` to read the file from github link but how do I just keep updating the files to google bucket.

Comment: One possibility would be to setup a CI/CD pipeline, automatically triggered by commits to the repo and which would just pull the repo content and use, as a build command, a wrapper (python if you want) script around the [`gsutil rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) cloud SDK utility to sync the repo content to the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the sync to be immediate (i.e., w/in seconds), you could set up a [cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) to periodically pull down the `.zip` archive of your repo, and upload it to Google Cloud Storage.

In your `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37
```

In your `cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
- description: "sync from git repo"
  url: /tasks/sync
  schedule: every 1 minute
```

In your `main.py`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import storage

app = Flask(__name__)

client = storage.Client(project='your-project-name')
bucket = client.get_bucket('your-bucket-name')

# Path to the archive of your repository's master branch
repo = 'https://github.com/your-username/your-repo-name/archive/master.zip'

@app.route('/tasks/sync')
def sync():
    with ZipFile(BytesIO(urlopen(repo).read())) as zipfile:
        for filename in zipfile.namelist():
            blob = storage.Blob(filename, bucket)
            blob.upload_from_string(zipfile.read(filename))
```

Deploy with:

```
$ gcloud app deploy
$ gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Google Cloud Build](https://github.com/GoogleCloudBuild). It lets you syncing your repo and using *[**gsutil**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gsutil)* you can automatically update your storage i.e `gs://acme-sales` on [each commits](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-on-github) to your GitHub repository:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['cp', '/workspace', 'gs://acme-sales']
```

You may start on GitHub by [connecting your repository](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcb-github-registration) i.e. `https://github.com/jc/<repo_name>` to Google Cloud Build using the link below:

> **https://github.com/apps/google-cloud-build**

[image: Automatically build containers or non-container artifacts on commits to your GitHub repository.]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer[s].

You can an option to ["Automatically Mirror from GitHub or Bitbucket"](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories), which is self descriptive. Or you can use an ["Automatic Build Trigger"](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds) directly with custom [build steps](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps) to perform certain actions.