# ICloud Drive Desktop Sync vs. Git - deleted files reappear and duplicates with number suffixes

Tags: git, macos, macos-catalina, icloud-drive, icloud-documents

Some words about my setup:

- MacOs Catalina 10.15.2
- Talking about `git` project folders on my Desktop which is synced with ICloud Drive sync Desktop & Document Folders option enabled

I have noticed that the following happens every now and then for some time now. Yesterday, I backed up my MacBook Pro to `MacOs Catalina 10.15.2` and this seems to have exacerbated the following pecularity I noticed this in my `git` initialized project folders:

A lot of times when I `deleted` `files` from my `local worktree` they randomly start reappearing in the worktree (sometimes even a day or more later) as `untracked files`.

Secondly, quite regularly, my existing files are suddenly seemingly `duplicated` - there are copies of them with number suffixes like for file foo there suddenly is `foo 2` and for file bar there is `bar 6`. They then also show up in `git status` as `untracked files`.
[example of duplicates appearing in worktree index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJxG9.png)

I also observed this behavior inside the `.git` folder.
[example of duplicates appearing in .git folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eo2n.png)

* Edit: It is noteworthy that the `<filename> 2` duplicates seem to stem from a previous time, sometimes even a month back (see "config 2" in .git folder screenshot above). I also noted (but this is not shown on the pictures I provided) that sometimes the number suffix is a random say "6" for example with no sequence of number suffixes (e.g. 1-5) leading up to that duplicated filename with number 6.

I have observed this happening every now and then but today it was all over the place. It could be that this problem especially appeared when I did some `git` ops like `git commit` `git reset` etc.

My assumption is that this must have something to do with `.git` not working well with `ICloud Drive Desktop file sync`.

So for now I will disable the `ICloud Drive Desktop file sync` option, and see if that will solve it.

**In the meantime, is anyone here familiar with the issue I have described and can anyone point me in the right direction, please?**

These posts seem to be related:

[Can Git and iCloud Drive be effectively used together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853139/can-git-and-icloud-drive-be-effectively-used-together)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255172/icloud-drive-and-git-repository/353123

[Github repo cloned to synced iCloud drive on multiple computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992312/github-repo-cloned-to-synced-icloud-drive-on-multiple-computers)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Keep your repository folders outside of your iCloud Drive-synced folders, and you should be fine. To be safe, do not combine VCS and file-syncing services together for the same directories/files. Use Github/GitLab/Bitbucket/etc. for synced access and centralised safekeeping.

**Long Answer:** iCloud Drive is a "consumer" product, meant for home users. If you are a developer working with version control software, you are considered a "professional" - and you will find that iCloud Drive (as well as other file-syncing solutions) is not a robust solution that will work well with your version-controlled folders. iCloud Drive (and other file-syncing services) is not aware of your VCS setup, and gets confused when you perform operations that make sweeping changes to directories - like switching branches or pulling changes. If you'd like to access your repositories on various computers/devices simultaneously, and have a 'central backup' of your repository files, just use one of the many repository hosting services - like Github, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc.

**Even Longer Answer:** The key problem that all 'auto-syncing' software has, is: how do we determine when a file has been changed, and should be synced? Do we check the actual file contents, assuming that a file with the same name should be the same file? How about tracking name changes? How about when we transfer files from one computer to another, and permissions (or dates) might change?

Often, file-syncing software will *watch the directories* as you work, for any changes. Once it detects that you've changed something in there, it will go through its routine to determine which files have changed, and to re-sync the needed ones.

There are many VCS operations - like pulling the latest changes in the repository, switching branches, or rolling back to a previous commit - which are likely to cause the file-syncing software to trigger its syncing routine. Depending on the actual syncing algorithm (how it determines what has changed, what steps are taken to sync, and how fast it is at actually performing the sync), it is likely that it will detect 'false positives', which will cause you to end up with duplicates.

In the particular case of the 'iCloud Drive + git' pair, we have a deadly combination: git is very fast at make sweeping changes to entire directory structures, and iCloud Drive is notoriously bad at detecting what has actually changed correctly - and is also *very slow* at syncing. This means that as git goes about switching branches and updating your working tree, iCloud Drive is likely to wrongly detect that files have changed, when they haven't. It will then tag these files for syncing. But because it is extremely slow at syncing, by the time it's halfway making its first duplicate copies, you might have already made another git change to your repository - which will cause you to now have 'file 3', and then 'file 4' and so on.

Hopefully this might change in the future, but in the meantime, the safest solution is to simply NOT keep your version-controlled repositories in any folder that is automatically synced. In this particular case, if you keep your repositories on any folder that is not 'Documents' or 'Desktop' - and not watched by iCloud Drive - then you should not have an issue with git.

Note that this is not an issue only with iCloud Drive and git. If you use any file syncing service (Dropbox, Google Drive, OwnCloud, Box, etc.) and any VCS (git, svn, fossil, etc.), you are likely to run into some kind of duplication, corruption, or security issue. :(

Lastly, it is worthwhile mentioning that the benefits provided by iCloud Drive - and other file-syncing services - are 'availability' (being able to access the repository from multiple computers and devices, keeping them synced) and 'security' (having a central location with a safe copy of all your files). You get these benefits already if you use any of the repository hosting services, such as Github, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc. So, in general, file-syncing your repositories is something that you don't actually need to do - just use the repository hosting services you are probably already using! ;-)

Comment: I have been experiencing this exact same behaviour and it's been doing my head in. Switching from my iMac to my MacBook Pro with a repo with multiple branches was causing me massive headaches with duplicate files being created, and massive changes to my open commits. So as per the advice below I'm going to move my git repositories out of the Documents folder and into a folder in my User folder that isn't synced.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use Git and syncing services (such as iCloud and Dropbox) together.

The reason is that these syncing services consider individual files as separate, logical documents to be synced.  When you're working on a word processing document or a spreadsheet, that assumption is true.  However, it's not true for Git repositories, which expect POSIX file system semantics to ensure the integrity of the repository and which modify many files in quick succession.

Because these syncing tools don't ensure that your repository state is read as a snapshot (either in the working tree or the `.git` directory), they're likely to corrupt your repository, and won't be effective as a backup or syncing tool.  If you want to use these service for backup, you should tar up the `.git` directory or create a Git bundle and put it into a location to be synced instead.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and the info on how to better use ICloud as a backup tool for `.git`. However, I do not really need ICloud as a backup tool. In fact, I switched the `Desktop & Documents` `sync` option off now, and the said issues have not reoccurred (yet). Can you please be more specific in your answer with regards to the bug I described - do you clearly attribute its cause to my ICloud Backup services syncing in the background, or is your answer more like a general best practice advice?

Comment: Your problem is due to the iCloud sync recreating old versions of files (that is, “syncing” them across systems) and not replacing them, but writing them with a ` 2` suffix because they've been changed.  So yes, your problem is definitely due to the iCloud sync functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to upvote your answer then, but I cannot, since I am a newbie. If you don't mind, upvote my question please, so that in return I should finally have some reputation to upvote your answer.