# Files in git repository are duplicated or removed and added

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

I've had the following two issues with a few local Git repositories on macOS 10.15.1 using Git 2.25.0, and I am not sure what causes this to happen:

1. The status of some or all files in a repository is removed and added, but there are no changes (not even line endings) between the removed and added file versions
2. Files get duplicated, e.g. if I have a file called `coverage.json`, an identical file called `coverage 2.json` is created. Sometimes additional copies such as `coverage 3.json` are also created

Solutions I've tried:

- Upgrading Git from the default macOS install to the 2.25.0 using Homebrew
- Removing git-related extensions from VS Code
- When files are removed and added, committing the changed. This just pushes off the issue—a short time later files will somehow show as removed and added again

The only solution I've found is either continually delete files and revert changes, or start a new, clean project. However, even on new projects this issue sometimes arises again.

Comment: That's strange. Are you using the git command line or some external tools/IDEs?

Comment: Usually through the command line, but occasionally though the source control functionality built in to VSCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any chance, are any of the repos in directories that are being sync'd with iCloud or another cloud-sync method? If so, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308049/icloud-drive-desktop-sync-vs-git-deleted-files-reappear-and-duplicates-with-n) may help you.

Comment: Ah yes that must be it, since I do have iCloud Drive turned on. Looks like I'll be turning that off. Thanks!