# How can I create private Git Repo for existing project with a specific path (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, ios, git, react-native, reactjs

How do I go about creating a private Git Repo to share with one other person for a React Native project on Atom editor, when it seems like the project is specific to my local directory path it is save on?

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some free online Git Repositories.
I am using BitBucket which is free for upto 5 users as of today.
https://bitbucket.org/

It is fast and easy to use, integrates well with azure.

You can use GitExtensions to commit your code to your online private repository on Bitbucket server. And share it your team members by simply adding them in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed all necessary dependencies listed in [React Native's Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/getting-started.html) – specifically, Node, Watchman, and the React Native CLI – add the following to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "YourAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.35.0"
  }
}
```

Then run: `npm install`.

Next run: `react-native upgrade`. This will install all of the directories that would have been installed had you initialized your project using React Native.

Once this is complete, you can run `react-native run-ios` to launch your app in the iOS Simulator. Note, the simulator may need to be opened ahead of time.

Everything should work out properly, assuming you have properly written your React Native app. At the very least you'll get error messages in the simulator to help you debug.

If you've never written a React Native app, navigate to your project's parent directory and run `react-native init MyProjectName`. Then copy and paste `index.ios.js` to your project's root directory.