# How can I use Git with OneDrive?

Tags: git, onedrive

I'm new to Git and was wondering if it would be sensible to store the Git local filestore/workspace in a Windows 10 OneDrive sync'ed folder.

I know it is maybe redundant (remote repository is a major point here)  But, if for example, my hard disk fails and I haven't pushed a recent commit, work *could* be lost.

Will it be dangerous to do this? E.g. would OneDrive get confused and sync an out of date Git file that handles what commits I've made and cause everything to go kaput? Or if there are any other technical reasons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1960799/2747593) (Though that question asks about Dropbox, the principles are the same.)

Comment: Ah!  My apologies.  I did not think of searching for other cloud-based storage (couldn't find anything on OneDrive issues)  Thanks, I'll look at that right now.

Comment: No prob. [It's okay to have (some) duplicates](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). I upvoted your question, because I think it's useful for the reason you mentioned. (Now if someone else searches for Git and OneDrive, they will be directed to that question.)

Comment: I meant to comment days ago - but [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1960799/2747593) was good.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5851299/6120800) was what I needed - basically, a corrupt repo is possible and therefore dangerous.