# Move a git repository outside Dropbox folder

Tags: git

I have project that is shared through Dropbox with someone who refuses to use git.
However, I like the branch and rollback characteristics of git.
For the moment, I the structure I have is the following:

```
Dropbox
├── Project
│   ├── Folder
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   ├── .git
│   ├── .gitattributes
│   ├── .gitignore
```

I also mount the `Project` folder as a `bind mount` somewhere else.
How could I move the `git` folder outside the Dropbox and still keep everything working?

Answer (score 1):

Never store a `.git` directory where Dropbox or some other similar sharing system will damage it (this is your current setup).  See [clu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215708/1256452) and [IBrum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939309/1256452) to [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960799/1256452) (Beware of the accepted answer there; see the comments!)