# Unwanted deleted files show up as changed files in my VS Code-Git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have cloned my Git repo and opened the project in VS Code. After a couple of minutes, VSCode-Source Control shows a couple of files as **Deleted**. If I try to discard the files as I don't need to push these changes, I get the VS Code error:

> Git: Unable to create file

**VSCode - Source Control**

[image: VSCode - Source Control]

**Error message**

[image: Error message]

I tried cloning the repo and each time these files showed up.

How should I fix this?

I tried discarding the files but was not able to.
This same works totally fine on my other laptop.

I have also tried running the long path command support but still the same:

```bash
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

Comment: Are you by chance missing a path(s) in your `.gitignore` and those files are being deleted as part of a run task?

Comment: I dont think so there is any in the .gitignore file. Same repo works fine in my other laptop.

Comment: do both your laptops have the same version of vs code? Can you provide exact steps to reproduce the issue with a fresh new repo?

Comment: Yes both laptop has same ver of VSCode. Do you mean to create a new git repo and then clone?

Steps:
-Clone the repo using Git Desktop

-Open the project folder using VSCode

-Checkout your feature branch

-Make some changes, commit and push your changes

-Wait for sometime

-Deleted files will show up in Souce Control tab

Comment: Is the directory into which you cloned the repo synched to the Cloud?

Comment: Yes the folder in on Onedrive.

Comment: That is a big, BIG, ***BIG*** no-no. Don't do that. It hurts. Onedrive will destroy your repository in no time.

Comment: Try cloning outside of OneDrive folder. Related reading: [Is it dangerous to put git directory in drive sync tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69056041/2745495)